# JQuery set select from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<table id="table_device">
    <tr>
        <td> First td </td>
        <td> Second td </td>
        <td> 
            <select class="base_MD">
                <option>A value</option>
                <option>Another value</option>
                <option>And another one</option>
                ...
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td> The value </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    ...
</table>
```

How do I set the `<select>` where the `<option>` matches with the 4th child (named `'The value'`) for each `<tr>` tag?

### EDIT

I tried the following

```
        $('#table_device').find('tr').each(function()
        {
            var value = $(this).find(':nth-child(4)').html();

            $('select').each(function()
            {
                if($(this).text() == value)
                {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                }

                $(this).eq(id).prop('selected', true);
            })
        });
```

But it did not work ... 
I'm sure it's not that complicated but my head will explode soon

Comment: What have you tried? What parts of [the API](http://api.jquery.com) have you looked at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each select element. get the text from next td and use it to set option by text. Like this:

```
$('#table_device select').each(function(){
 var nexttdtext = $(this).parent().next('td').text();
  $(this).find("option").filter(function() {
     return this.text == nexttdtext; 
  }).attr('selected', true);​
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: I have another `select` tag on each `tr`. Do I have to set a class or ID to the select that I want to setup ?

Comment: not required. check the demo. it exactly does what you want

Answer (score 1):

Bind an `onchange` event to the list. Find the selected option and the text inside it. And put it in the first row, last cell...

```js
$(function() {
  $('.base_MD').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $('#table_device tr:first-child td:last-child').text( value );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_device">
    <tr>
        <td> First td </td>
        <td> Second td </td>
        <td> 
            <select class="base_MD">
                <option>A value</option>
                <option>Another value</option>
                <option>And another one</option>
                ...
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td> The value </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    ...
</table>
```